# How to insert all columns from temp table to main table without repeating columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE persons_temp LIKE persons;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE INTO TABLE persons_temp ...
INSERT INTO persons SELECT * FROM persons_temp;
```

Problem: if my main `persons` table has an `id` autoincrement column as primary key, then during the insert I will get `java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` errors if the index of my main and temp table are out of sync.

Question: is it possible to copy-insert the temp table to main, without having to define each column explicit?

I thought of dropping the `id` column from temp table, but then on copy-insert I will get an error because the id will be missing.

Comment: One way is to use information_schema and generate a dynamic SQL query string and execute. But too much of a hassle unless you need to do this repeatedly for many other tables as well. In that case, it can be written as a stored procedure

Comment: What do you load into the the `id` column of the temp table (and how)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If you don't load the id on the temp_table you won't have matching column when you do the `insert select *`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm not getting your point. I'm asking how the `id` column of the temp table is being populated.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The temp table has the same ID autoincrement as the original table.

Answer (score 1):

In a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO persons SELECT * FROM persons_temp;
```

The shorthand of the INSERT with no columns list is to insert into *all* columns.

The shorthand of `SELECT *` is that it selects *all* columns.

SQL has no shorthand for "all-columns-but-one." You have you name the columns if you don't want all the columns.

You could rely on the implicit column list for the INSERT, and then use NULL in place of the primary key in the SELECT. The NULL will activate the auto-increment behavior.

```
INSERT INTO persons SELECT NULL, col2, col3, col4... FROM persons_temp;
```

But I recommend you do not rely on implicit column lists at all. Be explicit in your code. What if someone alters the `persons` table, adding or dropping a column, or changing the order of columns? Then your query would return a strange error, or worse, put values from the temp table into the wrong columns of `persons`.

---

Based on Paul Spiegel's comment above, I think one could do this after creating the temp table:

```
UPDATE persons_temp SET id = NULL;
```

Then do your `INSERT... SELECT *` query, and it will use the implicit columns, but the NULLs will activate the auto-increment of `persons` as it inserts.

Comment: I said almost the same and got -2 :shrug:

Comment: Your answer was correct, but the way you wrote it sounds like you didn't pay attention to the OP's requirement to use implicit column lists. I'm trying to write an explanation of why that's not possible.

Comment: I think he add that comment after I read the question and he saw my answer

Comment: Maybe so. The edit history shows that requirement in the original post, but I think quick edits within the first few minutes are combined with the original post, not shown in the history as separate edits.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to get an upvote on this question, because none of us can give the OP the answer they wish for.

Comment: How can you read my mind? I didn't write that :-) However - You need to drop the PK and change the id to be nullable first.

Comment: Yes, good point, we haven't seen the temp table definition. If it has a constraint on `id` that will have to be changed. I wanted to give you credit for the idea. I didn't think of it until I saw your comment at the top about what is loading into `id` in the temp table.

Comment: The temp table is a copy of original. `CREATE TABLE persons_temp LIKE persons;` The problem is when try to move from `persons_temp` to `persons`. So remove the constraint on `persons_temp` doesnt solve the problem when moving to `persons`

Answer (score 1):

Change the autoincrement value before the load:

```
SET @maxvalue = SELECT MAX(id) for persons

ALTER TABLE persons_temp AUTO_INCREMENT = @maxvalue + 1;
```

Comment: This is subject to a race condition. What if other clients are inserting new rows to persons continually?

Comment: I know. But OP is using a LOAD statement. I guess race is less like it.  Also if OP doesnt want to put the names of the columns cant see other way.

Comment: Correct, there is no other way. They will just have to type a few column names, or develop code to make a list based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO persons (MAYBY_ID, COL1, COL2, ...) INSERT * FROM persons_temp;
```

Comment: Yes, I do this before answer you

Comment: Watch the image (Open the link) and send me your query.
https://pasteboard.co/IA8dNPx.png

Comment: I didn't give a downvote (someone else must have), but I don't recognize `INSERT ... INSERT * FROM ...` as valid MySQL syntax. Maybe some other brand of database?

Comment: Thank you, No problem ;)